# How to convert longitude and latitude into Array in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, geojson

I use Ruby on Rails 5.2 Mongoid and Geocoder for geocoding

```
class Place
  include Mongoid::Document

  include Geocoder::Model::Mongoid
  field :coordinates, type: Array
  field :latitude, type: Float
  field :longitude, type: Float

  before_save :set_geojson

  def set_coordinates
    self.coordinates = # { type: "Point", coordinates: [ self.latitude, self.longitude ] }
  end

  reverse_geocoded_by :coordinates, address: :street_address
  after_validation :reverse_geocode
end
```

I need to convert longitude and latitude to get `{ type: "Point", coordinates: [ 40, 5 ] }`
or something similar.

Comment: The question in your title doesn't quite match the content. Where is this string you want to be an array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought.

```
  before_validation :set_geojson

  def set_geojson
    self.coordinates = [self.longitude.to_f, self.latitude.to_f]
  end
```

Comment: `self` is superfluous if you're in the Place model.